# simulate mouse drag in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have this small piece of code and i want to to simulate the drag of div from one point to another .. i used jquery.simulate.js script for this but i get error in the console saying.. "$.ui.mouse._mouseDown is not a function"

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
.box {
    background-color:#b0c4de;
}   

</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.simulate.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var myDiv = $("#myDiv");

    myDiv.draggable();

    // This will set enough properties to simulate valid mouse options.
    $.ui.mouse.options = $.ui.mouse.defaults;

    var divOffset = myDiv.offset();

    // This will simulate clicking down on the div - works mostly.
    $.ui.mouse._mouseDown({
            target: myDiv,
            pageX: divOffset.left,
            pageY: divOffset.top,
            which: 1,

            preventDefault: function() { }
    });
});

</script>


</head>

<body>
<div id="myDiv">hello</div> 

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thougt of using `.animate ()` ?

Example:

```
$("#block").animate({
    marginRight: "0.4in",
    opacity: 0.4,
    marginLeft: "0.6in",
    fontSize: "3em",
    borderWidth: "10px"
  }, 1500 );
```

So you could animate the repositioning of your div !

Answer (score 9):

If you really want to simulate a drag (& drop), use the jQuery simulate extended plugin:
http://j-ulrich.github.com/jquery-simulate-ext

Then you can use

```
$('#myDiv').simulate("drag-n-drop", {dx: 50});
```

to drag the div 50px to the right.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the plugin.

Comment: And how do you drag to the specified element? not x/y

Comment: @Nakilon Check out the [documentation of the plugin](https://github.com/j-ulrich/jquery-simulate-ext/blob/master/doc/drag-n-drop.md): `$('#myDiv').simulate("drag-n-drop", {dragTarget: otherDiv});`